# PHP to Typescript conversion

Tags: php, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to build a function for firebase to call a url on command via a POST method. I've currently implemented GET methods just fine but the POST method has me scratching my head.

I've got some sample code for calling via fetch but I'm not sure where the parameters in this following snippet need to go:

```
<?php

$url = 'https://profootballapi.com/schedule';

$api_key = '__YOUR__API__KEY__';

$query_string = 'api_key='.$api_key.'&year=2014&week=7&season_type=REG';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $result;

?>
```

Here's what my sample code for the POST request looks like:

```
const apiKey = "myAPIkey";
const url = "https://profootballapi.com/schedule";
const response = await fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: 'api_key'= apiKey, '&year=2018&week=7&season_typeRG';
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}});

if (!response.ok) {/* Handle */}

  // If you care about a response:
  if (response.body !== null) {
    functions.logger.log(response.body); 
  }
```

Comment: I think this is a fair question seeking debugging help, but I think the title will attract negativity. It's common to see posts like "Can someone convert this code for me plz?" type questions that provide no effort on the part of the asker. I appreciate seeing your attempt to convert it on your own. I can't think of a better title off hand  :-)

Comment: Thank you for the feed back, long time listener, first time caller lol. I'll keep it in mind!

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close. You just have some syntax level issues in your TypeScript:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

You passed in the url correctly.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query_string);
```

This is just providing an HTTP body to the request You've already attempted this in the fetch, but you have some syntax issues. You should replace the `body` with this:

```
body: `api_key=${apiKey}&year=2018&week=7&season_type=REG`
```

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

This is free. `fetch` automatically returns the response in `response`.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Assuming this code will run on the browser, you won't be able to disable this. It's telling the client to verify the server's SSL certificate. you should avoid disabling this if you can help it.

I tested this code and got somewhat reasonable results in Chrome's debugging tools:

```js
const foo = async function () {
  const apiKey = "myAPIkey";
  const url = "https://profootballapi.com/schedule";
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: `api_key=${apiKey}&year=2018&week=7&season_type=REG`,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
  });

  return response;
}

foo().then(response => console.log(response));
```

It produces a 500 error, but I suspect this has to do with not having a valid API key. I'll leave it to you to sort out how to submit a valid API request.

Comment: You shouln't be building the POST parameter string with concatenation. Use a purpose-built method that properly encodes the characters. In PHP this would be `http_build_query`, for example.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much, I figured I was close but wasn't sure of the syntax needed for the body.